# server side rendering and client side rendering ReactJs

Tags: express, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

I am using react-router to handle both server side rendering and client side rendering in React. But as entry point of my app also has following code :

```
 Router.run(routes, Router.HistoryLocation, function(Handler, state) {
  React.render(<Handler/>, document.body)
   })
```

rendering is getting called twice. How to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You will see two renders because first the server renders your app and sends it to the browser; then React renders your code a second time in the frontend, this goes into the virtual DOM, which will see no difference, so it won't change your actual DOM. 
It needs that second render to get your code into the virtual DOM to be alive on the frontend, ready for the next move.